# libevent on mac, make install

Tags: c, macos, makefile, libevent

I follow the README to install the libevent on Mac os
In the last step, make install, It shows

```
Making install in include
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 .././install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/include'
 .././install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/include/event2'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  event2/buffer.h event2/buffer_compat.h event2/bufferevent.h event2/bufferevent_compat.h event2/bufferevent_ssl.h event2/bufferevent_struct.h event2/dns.h event2/dns_compat.h event2/dns_struct.h event2/event.h event2/event_compat.h event2/event_struct.h event2/http.h event2/http_compat.h event2/http_struct.h event2/keyvalq_struct.h event2/listener.h event2/rpc.h event2/rpc_compat.h event2/rpc_struct.h event2/tag.h event2/tag_compat.h event2/thread.h event2/util.h '/usr/local/include/event2'
 .././install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/include'
 .././install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/include/event2'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  ./event2/event-config.h '/usr/local/include/event2'
Making install in sample
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in test
make  install-am
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
```

There are many "Nothing to be done". How to fix them?

Comment: You don't, they are normal. For example, nothing in the `test` folder should be installed, but the make process, due to they the build system works, still tries to go into the subdirectory. But since there's nothing to do for installation, it simply says so.

Comment: It means you've already installed it. To force it to be installed again do `sudo make -B install`.

Comment: "Nothing to be done" effectively means "I've already done everything you're asking me to do". You could do a `make clean` first, which will ditch any existing object files, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to fix them there are normal. To make sure you've install the lib properly look for the `event2` directory in /usr/local/include.

You can start writing your code.